# Как правильно разместить графику в приложении?

Tags: java, android

делаю графическую сцену с анимацией

возник вопрос где хранить и как правильно отдавать графические ресурсы?

(правильно, оптимально, не раздувая память)

есть классы: Screen и Unit

графика хранится в подобном файле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
юнитов на экране может быть много

предполагаю парсить графику в Screen и отдавать в Unit

вопрос, как оптимально (с точки зрения расходов памяти) отдавать ресурсы в Unit?

(отдавать массив или ссылку на Screen)

Answer (score 0):

Хранить кадры в Screen, а уже классы Unit будут использовать графику с Screen. если юнитов будет много, то на каждого юнита отдельной графики не напасёшся

Comment: т.к. переменные в JAVA передаются не по ссылке, а по значению, возникает вопрос, есть ли разница (расхода памяти) в передаче массива графики или this самого Screen?

Comment: Массив передаётся по ссылке. Задайте вопрос передачи массива подробнее. Если передавать массив с одной переменной в другую, то он **не копируется**. Копируются только примитивные типы.